# C# regex matching on one or many digit(s) followed by a star but not when the full string is 05* and 07*

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a C# regex expression with these rules:

The last char has to be a *

The first char has to be a digit and can be followed by any number of digit but there must be at least 1 digit to start the string.

The complete string CAN'T be 05* or 07*

So these should match:

111*

12*

1*

Should NOT match on ONLY
05*
07*

This works for the match cases:

```
Regex oneOrManyDigitWithTrailingStar = new(@"\A\d+[*]$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This works to exclude 05* or 07*:

```
Regex IsNotZeroFiveStarOrZeroSevenStarOnly = new(@"(?s)(?<!\A05\*|\A07\*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I've tried pretty much everything I could think of and read all the questions I could find to  no avail. I can't seem to be able to combine both approach.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Honestly doesn't seem like you tried at all. `first char has to be a digit` ^\d, `last char has to be a *`  \\*$ , `The complete string CAN'T be 05* or 07*`  ^(?!0[57]\\*$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?!0[57]\*\z)[0-9]+\*\z
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0[57]\*\z)` - no `05*`/`07*` allowed immediately to the right and up to the end of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more ASCII digits
- `\*` - a literal `*` char
- `\z` - end of string.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!0%5B57%5D%5C*%5Cz%29%5B0-9%5D%2B%5C*%5Cz&i=111*).